# Calcular cos(x) mediante aproximación de serie Taylor

Tags: c, double

soy nueva en este mundillo, estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta. Me he trabado en este ejercicio y no tengo a nadie para consultar. Cualquier ayuda es valorada. Muchas Gracias.

Necesito escribir un programa que primero pida al usuario que introduzca por teclado un número real x y un número natural n (n>0) y a continuación muestre por pantalla el valor numérico de cos(x), utilizando la siguiente aproximación por serie de Taylor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, debo declarar las variables reales de tipo double. Aquí dejo un ejemplo de ejecución:

**Introduzca un valor real (x): 0**

**Introduzca un valor natural (n): 5**

**cos(0.00) = 1.00**

Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
 {  
    int i, j,k,n, aux;
    double nreal;
    int natural;
    int aux_fact;
    int x_inf;
    int x_sup;
    double x_div_in;
    int uno;
    double suma_total;

    printf("Escriba un valor x real");
    scanf("%lf", &nreal);
    printf("Escriba un valor n natural"); 
    scanf("%d", &natural);
    
    for( i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        x_sup = nreal*nreal*i;
        aux_fact = 2*i;
        if (aux_fact == 0)
        {
            x_inf = 1;
        }
        for(j = 0; j < aux_fact; j++)
        {
            x_inf = aux_fact*(aux_fact-i);
        }
        x_div_in = x_sup/x_inf;
        for( k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            uno = uno*-1;
            if( uno == 0)
            {
                uno = -1; 
            }                       
        }
        x_div_in = x_div_in*uno;    
        suma_total = suma_total + x_div_in; 
            
    }
    printf("\n cos(%f) = %f", nreal, suma_total);
        
 }
```

¿Cuál sería el código correcto?

Comment: Tienes varias variables que usas sin haber declarado: `nnatural`, `n` y `k`
varias veces. Supongo que `nnatural` esta mal escrito y te refieres a
`natural`, esa correccion es rapida. Y luego declara `n` y `k` (Mejor si los
declaras donde los uses).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo acabo de editar, pero sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: `scanf("%f", &nreal);` Estas diciendo que vas a leer un `float`, pero lo
escribes a una variable `double`. El especificador de formato tiene que ser
`%lf`, no `%f`. `x_div_in = x_sup/x_inf;` Esta divicion parara con una perdida
de datos, ya que estas dividiendo enteros y lo asignas a un `double`. Tienes que
aprender a leer los errores y avisos del compilador. No haría falta que yo te
dijera nada de esto, ellos ya te hubieran indicado los errores en primer lugar.

Comment: Es verdad que se me han pasado, pero aún corrigiéndolos, el código no se ejecuta de forma correcta

Comment: Si se te pide por [serie de Taylor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_de_Taylor), deberías de considerar también en dónde está centrada la función, de lo contrario estás haciendo una serie de Maclaurin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he conseguido resolver, dejo el código por si alguien tiene que hacer el mismo ejercicio:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x, elem, sum;
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Introduzca un valor real (x): ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Introduzca un valor natural (n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0, sum=0; i<=n; i++) {
        for(j=1, elem=1; j<=2*i; j++) {
            elem = elem * x/j;
        }
        if (i%2==0) {
            sum = sum + elem;
        } else {
            sum = sum - elem;
        }
    }
    printf("Cos(%.2lf) = %.2lf\n", x, sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te respondo con las **variables** **n** y **x** ya con un valor predeterminado, para avanzar mas rápido. Encárgate tu de la parte de la entrada de datos a esta variables por parte del usuario, tal como ya haces en tu código. La diferencia es que yo declaro ambas variables de tipo **double**.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double factorial(double n)
{
    double resultado = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        resultado = resultado * i;
    }

    return resultado;
}

int main (void)
{
    int n = 5;
    double x = 30 * (3.1415 / 180);
    double duplo = 0;
    double unidad = 0;
    double potencia = 0;
    double sumatoria = 0;
    double coseno = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        duplo = 2 * i;
        unidad = (i % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
        potencia = pow(x, duplo);
        sumatoria = (potencia / factorial(duplo)) * unidad;
        coseno = coseno + sumatoria;
    }

    //Imprimir coseno
}
```

Primero hacemos la **función Factorial**, la cual nos va a devolver el factorial del numero pasado como parámetro, de esta forma estructuramos el código y lo hacemos mas legible y fácil de mantener.

Ya dentro del **metodo main** declaramos las variables necesarias, a la **variable n** le damos por defecto el valor **5**, y la **variable x** seria **30**. Y aquí viene un paso muy importante, ya que debes **convertir de grados a radianes**, para ello hacemos el siguiente calculo:

```
double x = 30 * (3.1415 / 180); 
//los grados * pi / 180, mientras mas decimales usemos en la constante pi mas 
//exacto será el calculo. 1 radian = 180 grados
```

Ya después haríamos el calculo de la serie haciendo la sumatoria correspondiente desde **i = 0** hasta **n** utilizando un **ciclo for**. Después de salir de esta **ciclo for** ya tendríamos el calculo del coseno, por tanto imprimimos dicho resultado.

Para trabajar con las potencias debes incluir la biblioteca **math.h**.

Comment: El codigo es en `C`, no `Java`. El `public` antes de la funcion resultara en un error de compilacion. Y el `// Dentro del método main` perfectamente puedes sustiturirlo por `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Pablochaches, arreglado, gracias